# How to remove telephone number as required field in billing and shipping on admin side?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sql, shipping-address, billing-address

How to change telephone number to not being required on the admin side billing and shipping information?

Could this be done with some SQL query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the SQL query for setting the attribute `telephone` to not required.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'telephone';
```

You might want this implemented in a setup script if you wish to package it in an extension.

> This does not override any frontend code, which may still require the telephone.

Comment: you need also to edit `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php` comment out `getTelephone()` check.

Comment: @LucaS That's not necessary.

Comment: It is necessary with magento 1.9.3.8 and iwd checkout, if you don't edit `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php` it returns error "insert phone number". I don't try it with default checkout, but i think it returns error anyway because it checks phone number as required.